# How linux kernel interfaces with android runtime and libraries ?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, open-source, linux-device-driver

I have been working on project in which i had to add an engine or platform at second layer of android where libraries and dalveik Virtual Machine are located. my question is how should i add something at second layer and provide Linux kernel resources to it.

how Linux kernel interact with libraries and android run time to execute applications?
what are sources or resources that i can explore to make feel free to speak.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, words you used here have meaning which differs from your requirement.

What I think you need to implement set of libraries.

For that you first need to understand the working of Linux OS, and then how android utilize it for its purpose.

Here i'll try to make some brief description for your requirement.

Linux Kernel have two layers - User space and kernel space, user space is responsible for interaction with users and kernel is responsible for interacting with hardware. And how both interact with each other is by procedure called System Call.

Core concept is also same here. Top three layers as shown are the part of user space. Bottom layer is kernel layer.

[image: layers of android]

here also mode of communication between user space and kernel space is system call. But usually only layers of library plays the role to make communication between the above layers and the kernel.

Then comes your requirement.

> how should i add something at second layer and provide Linux kernel resources to it

You also have to do the same, you can add a new library, in which using system calls interface you can talk to kernel.

Also In order to access the methods of the shared library from java code, you need to bring in `JNI wrappers` around the methods exposed from your shared lib.

Then after Cross-compiling  you can get .so file [here you can refer a sample how to develop a shared library for android](http://honeypod.blogspot.in/2007/12/shared-library-hello-world-for-android.html)

That's all, as per your requirement you can also develop your library.

Then you need to push that file into `/system/lib` using `adb push` command. Their can be a case push may not work, then try to mount /system

```
adb shell mount -o remount,rw /system //and then again try to push
adb push mylibrary.so /system/lib/mylibrary.so
adb shell chmod 644 /system/lib/mylibrary.so // set the permission
```

If sometime, you still can't able to push that file, try to root that device.

After you'll reboot the device that library will work.

Comment: well let me be more clear i  have to insert docker engine at the second layer on your given diagram, but in order to do so i have to know the protocols and interface that the native libraries do with Linux kernel( of android). so to run the containers i have to provide resources through the interface of docker engine and linux kernel. hope i have explain my point of view. ?

Comment: so you mean docker engine will provide api to upper layers and will talk to kernel layer? any other use of docker engine?

Comment: well i am trying do it. but can't find a way to do so. https://www.docker.com/what-docker

Comment: answer given is the basic concept behind introducing anything on second layer. Though virtualization is a vast field, including all aspect of development virtualization is very broad, can't be included here. Provided method tells how to utilize kernel resources, you have to use these basics with virtualization to build that type of functionality.

Comment: Instead of library you have to program a whole application, use android ndk for that purpose.

Comment: By "program" you mean to say develop whole docker engine that is used to run containers?

Comment: not whole, core part you can use, few interfaces to kernel will be the same, and above layer interface will be difference, you need to introduce jni wrapper for those. Whole i mean to say, a new one with changes